# Instance of class is null in other class

Tags: c#, .net

I added a value to a property of my `Events.cs` model class in a method of my controller class. I want to use this value in another class through the instance of this model class.

At run time of the method, this instance wasnt null, also in other classes. But after the method runned through, i cannot use the added value in the other class because the instance is null. How can i use this instance with the added value?

Add value method in Controller class:

```
public Events _events;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(Events events)
{
    _events = events;
    return Json("true", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Instance of `Events.cs` in other class:

```
public Events _events;
```

Comment: A controller is initiated when a request is received, it is then disposed of when the request ends.

Comment: only because two classes have a member of the same type doesn´t mean those members are actually the same objects. You have to set the property within your second class somewhere. Currently your two properties are completely unrelated.

Comment: Object in controller is local to the controller, it can not be accessed outside of it unless it is passed or exposed publicly.

Comment: Can i set the value of the property in the object of my ``Events`` model class in my other class and use this property even the Action Method of my controller class runned through? ``[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Search(Events events)
        {
            otherClass.events.EventDay = events.EventDay;

            return Json("true", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }``

Answer (score 0):

This is because the field `_events` only last the duration of the instance of your class. Each new web request constructs a new controller to perform the task and then the controller is destructed upon the request completion.